# ExpandableListview Custom child row

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In my application I am using and "Expandable listview". Suppose if user selects an child row I have to have to make that imageview visible otherwise don't.The following code make my imageview visible when user selects a child.But if user selects another child  the previously selected child row image is also visible i don't want that..If user selects a child that child's imageview should be visible.Also if i select another group the previously selected "Child Row" is not visible...

Child Row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvPlayerName" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="30dip" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/selected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/tick_icon"/>


</RelativeLayout>


ImageView imageView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.selected);
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Please help me to solve this..

Answer (score 1):

In child_row.xml ImageView visibility gone. then in your onChildClick() make visible the image ( imageview)

```
   public boolean onChildClick(
        ExpandableListView parent, 
        View v, 
        int groupPosition,
        int childPosition,
        long id) {

    //Write the code for image visible 
  }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate??

Comment: firstly in chil_row.xml make Imageview Visibility:gone/Invisible. Your activity should implement OnChildClickListener and implement the above method. its get called when user clicks on child list and visible the image

Comment: K tried for that..How can i get that particular row(view ) of child and make that image visible??See my edited post..App is crashing..

Comment: Their are 2 ways we can do while passing the values to adapter class add one more attribute flag. once click on child change the flag value and refresh the list

Comment: try out your self first i will guide you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tvPlayerName" 
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="30dip" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/selected"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_share"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

**In your java class**

```
textView.setFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
    }
}
});
```

Hope this will help.